# How to backtest a strategy from a specified date

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to backtest a strategy from a specified date ,eg 2020-01-01.

The code is working, but I get a warning

> line 12: The function 'ta.crossover' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope.

How to fix it?

```
//@version=5
strategy(title="GOLDEN",  overlay=true)
sma20 = ta.sma(close,20)
sma60 = ta.sma(close,60)
plot(sma20,color=color.orange)
plot(sma60,color=color.blue)
backtest_year = input.int(2020,"Y")
backtest_month = input.int(1,"M",minval=1,maxval=12,step = 1)
backtest_day = input.int(1,"D",minval=1,maxval=31,step = 1)
backtest_startDate = timestamp(backtest_year,backtest_month,backtest_day,0,0,0)
if (time>= backtest_startDate)
    to_long = ta.crossover(sma20,sma60)
    to_close = ta.crossunder(sma20,sma60)
    strategy.entry("golden",strategy.long,qty=1000, when = to_long)
    strategy.close("golden",qty = 1000, when = to_close)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing it like that, you can use `timestamp` in your `input()` function so you would need one input for start time and one input for the end time and it look pretty cool :)

Coming to the warning you are getting. It is because you have that function in a local scope. Try putting it in global scope.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © vitruvius

//@version=5
strategy(title="GOLDEN",  overlay=true)

in_start_time = input(defval=timestamp("01 Jan 2021 00:00 +0000"), title="Start Time", group="Time Settings")
in_end_time = input(defval=timestamp("31 Dec 2031 00:00 +0000"), title="End Time", group="Time Settings")

in_window = time >= in_start_time and time <= in_end_time

sma20 = ta.sma(close,20)
sma60 = ta.sma(close,60)

plot(sma20,color=color.orange)
plot(sma60,color=color.blue)

to_long = ta.crossover(sma20,sma60)
to_close = ta.crossunder(sma20,sma60)

if (in_window and to_long)
    strategy.entry("golden",strategy.long,qty=1000)

if (in_window and to_close)
    strategy.close("golden",qty = 1000, when = to_close)
```

Comment: Pine's execution engine cannot handle gaps, it not just creates empty "holes" in its Series, it creates outright corrupt data. Any statement that creates a value in a variable that has the data-type of `Series` has to be put into the global scope. That means its value cannot be set based on a condition or Pine might think it sometimes won't be set, and then the above mayhem happens. Also `FOR` loop might look like it is not a local scope, but it is. Its behavior is also nondeterministic.